# prevent sending email if the "To:" field contains my own email address, via Outlook rule?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Gmail, if you're having `conversation` (thread of email-exchange) with `someone`, if you hit "Reply" to any email in the `conversation`  (whether sent by you or `someone`), the `To:` field will contain `someone`'s email address.

I love this feature in Gmail.

Recently, my employer forced us to start using Outlook. Outlook doesn't have this afore-mentioned feature.

However, I'm thinking that there might be some way to configure `Outlook rules` as follows:

- if I hit `Reply` on an email, and the `To:` field contains my own email address (or some pre-specified email address), Outlook should prevent the email from being sent, and give some kind of message.

Looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, this is what I did:

[image]

Comment: I'm afarid there is no such rule for this in Outlook client. You may ask this problem in developer forum.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev&filter=alltypes&sort=firstpostdesc. Besides, you can also set a defer delivery rule as a workaround.